# PHP sqlite sql issue

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I have a database that contains a date/time field that uses text. It's typed as `DATE/TIME`. It looks like "`2020-01-21 19-33-22Z`" when viewed in DB Browser.  I want to order the table in `DESC` date/time sequence.  Using DB Browser I can execute a SQL statement that looks like:

`SELECT * FROM LOG ORDER BY QSODATE DECS`

That statement works in DB Browser, but not in my PHP 7.3.6 environment.  When I run the PHP program i don't get any errors, I do get a connection to the table, and I can pull data from the table, but the order is not correct.  The order looks like the raw table with no order invoked.

Edit 1/2/2020 
**From DB Browser:
Result: 7251 rows returned in 2480ms
At line 1:
SELECT * FROM LOG ORDER by qsodate DESC**

That results in this partial top row which is not correct:
20200122192000960   xx3xxx  40m FT8 2020-01-21 22:35:00Z

The whole record would be meaningless, but this snippet contains the date and time that I am trying to set the order on.  Now that I look I see the I swapped two letters in "DESC" when I typed the first example. Sorry.

However the date/time that should be at the top is: 2020-01-31 18:26:00Z

The date/time in the example is the un-ordered date/time.

The PHP code line is:

$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM LOG ORDER by qsodate DESC");

Comment: The sqlite snippet in the question gives syntax error and won't run in either DB Browser or php. It would be important to see 1) what query is actually executed in php and 2) some of the data that is returned that shows an example of wrong order. You could edit this question to give more information.

Comment: You are right.  This is a cut and paste from DB Browser:

Comment: [sqlite does not have a date/time datatype](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Data in this format `2020-01-21 22:35:00Z` will sort as a string. Am I understanding correctly: the first row that DB Browser returns has `2020-01-21 22:35:00Z` in qsodate. But you expect it to return the row with qsodate =  `2020-01-31 18:26:00Z` as the first row? I originally thought you were saying that DB Browser and php were returning the rows in different orders now I think you mean  that both return the rows in the "wrong" order? Can you clarify please? Are you sure `qsodate` is the correct column?

Comment: Yes 'qsodate' is the right column.  I am a ham radio operator, and this data is included in the application that I use to keep track of contacts.  The sqlite data file is a direct no conversion copy of the data file.  DB Browser tells me that column is DATETIME and there are two of those data types in table.  In addition one of the indexes embedded in the database includes 'qsodate'.  Yes - in both DB Browser and in my PHP app the order is the same.  In the application that manages the database (Log4OM) the sequence starts with the 2020-01-31 date.

Comment: The 2020-01-31 date would not sort to the top if the column starts with blank. That might be difficult for the eye to detect but not the computer. Would expect length of qsodate to be 20 for all rows. Does a sql like `select length(qsodate), count(*) from log GROUP BY length(qsodate)` confirm that?

Comment: I tried 'select * from log order by trim(qsodate)'.  That made no difference.  That was late last night.  today I will try what you suggested.

Comment: 2/3/2020 - New Clue: If I open the data file in Log4OM(this generates the file), DB Browser or SQLiteStudio I get a reported 7267 records.  PHP shows 7251 records.  Now I wonder if there is some discrepancy in the data file.  I ported over 7251 records from a previous version of Log4OM v1.  Log4OM v2 added the last 16,  I used (as recommended) an interim file ADIF which is a common data exchange format that hams use.  It uses data tags similar to but not the same as XML.

Comment: If the php only shows 7251 records (the number of rows in the v1 database), is it possible the program is connecting to the v1 database?

Comment: Good question but no.  I just checked at the connection line in PHP and the file is correct.  Thanks.

Comment: How does the "_PHP show[s] 7251 records_"? If DB Browser returns 7267 rows and PHP is connected to the same database and executes the same query it will (eventually/possibly) retrieve 7267 rows. Technically this `$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM LOG ORDER by qsodate DESC");` doesn't retrieve _any_ rows, it returns a result object which must be further processed. Is the problem in that "further processing"?

Comment: Thank you to all who tried to help.  I am not sure what changed at this point, but everything works as it should now.  I suspect that (as prompted by on comment) that in spite of checking path names and file names, I had it wrong. Using this line does in fact give me the correct result: $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM LOG ORDER by qsodate DESC");.  Rows are extracted and analyzed elsewhere in the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert qsodate to a [valid sqlite timestring](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) (i.e. "2020-01-21 19:33:22Z" then you can convert it to unixepoch and sort chronologically.

```
SELECT * FROM LOG ORDER by strftime('%s',qsodate) DESC
```

For reference...

```
select strftime('%s',"2020-01-21 19:33:22Z") 'unixepoch'

Unixepoch
----------
1579635202
```